# Azure ASP Multi Region Replication

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are using App Service Plan which is Zone Redundant, but we want to cross replicate across another region. Is it possible to deploy ASP in multiple regions? Also let me how to create app service and make avail it in multiple zones.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please refer [Multi regional deployment with  Azure App Services](https://medium.com/codebet/multi-regional-deployment-with-azure-devops-and-azure-app-services-9be626b43947)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.